# Failed building wheels for opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, pip, python-wheel

I have tried updating pip, pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel, and also tried by specifying version of that "pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56" it successfully install opencv-python but throws error when I import cv2 "module not found"
I'm using raspberry pi 3 model b+ and raspbian OS 32bit. How to solve this error and install opencv-pythonplease guide me

Tried installing it by github repository also, it says can't install cmake

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you've not installed open-cv to the same Python version that you're using for your import.

Raspbian has two Python versions; Python 2.7 and a Python 3 version. The regular `pip` command is being called under Python 2.7 and I'm assuming you're trying to use Python 3 to code.

To install it under your Python 3 version, put `python3 -m` before your pip install command.

E.g. `python3 -m pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56`

Comment: Successfully installed but it gives error when I import cv2 it says import error: libcblas.so.3 cannot open shared object file no such file or directory . Tried installing using sudo apt-get libatlas-base-dev , libcblas , it says Failed to fetch http://raspbian.mirror.net.in

Comment: That's odd; not had a problem with mirrors before. Maybe changing to a different mirror like these threads suggest will help?

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9307/apt-get-installation-doesnt-work-on-raspberry-pi

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103539/could-not-connect-to-raspbian-raspberrypi-org-in-raspberry-pi-3